# Android: Z-Order with a screen-wide clickblocker-view

Tags: android, view, click, z-order

Edit: Solved. The problem disappeared when I made all my custom views override Button instead of View.

I'm trying to programmatically create a screen-sized invisible view which should capture all click events, thereby blocking all underlying elements. But I'm having some trouble.

The intended goal is that when the user clicks a certain button, a menu is created. While this menu is up, the other buttons that were on the page should no longer function. Clicking on the menu should make stuff happen, clicking anywhere else should make the menu disappear and make the other elements work again.

I've managed to create the screen wide view just fine, and it captures clicks and destroys the menu whenever the user clicks a point that is not already covered by a button. When the user does click on a spot that contains a button however, only the button's onclickevent is handled, and not that of my clickblocker. It should be the other way around. 
This leads me to think it's a z-order problem (but not 100% sure). 
Unfortunately I'm trying to target older versions, which don't have support for view.setZ(), and view.bringToFront() doesn't appear to do what I want it to do.

Here's the code for the viewblocker:

```
public class ClickBlockerView extends View{

    public ClickBlockerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(C.GetWindowWidth(getContext()), C.GetWindowHeight(getContext()));
    }

    public static ClickBlockerView CreateClickBlocker(Context context){
        ClickBlockerView c = new ClickBlockerView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        c.setLayoutParams(params);
        c.setId(R.id.clickBlocker);
        c.setClickable(true);
        return  c;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling it (from inside another view):

```
private void createMenuAndClickblocker(){
       ClickBlockerView clickblocker = ClickBlockerView.CreateClickBlocker(getContext());
       clickblocker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    destroyMenu();
                }
        });
        ((RelativeLayout) this.getParent()).addView(clickblocker);
        clickblocker.bringToFront();

        createMenu();
        requestLayout();
    }
```

Does anyone have some idea how to fix this? Other solutions to the problem are welcome too. I'd rather not have to use xml though (it would have to be added to every activity)

Update:

Apparently, the z-ordering goes fine with spinners and checkboxes, but not with buttons and my custom views. Odd...

Update 2:

When drawn, the shape is shown to correctly fill up the screen, but it is also drawn below the other custom views, even though it is created later and brought to the front. 
Strangely enough, the click functionality has meanwhile completely stopped functioning, even though I didn't change anything in the code for this clickblocker.